# Can you have a Single-Page Application in Nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-router-dom

I am looking at Nextjs but have a questions about running a SPA in Nextjs. I need two separate sides to my application. One that is SSR, and another that is CSR while the user is logged in **and** browsing private routes.

I would like to use React-Router-dom for CSR portions, but I am unsure how that interferes with Nextjs' built in router.

I am completely unfamiliar with nextjs, so all information is super helpful at this point.
Thank you.

Comment: I think it wouldn't interfere as long as your nested (logged in) routes are subsets of their parent routes. I encourage you to try it yourself and post a question if it doesn't work the way you expect it to. With that said, why do you want to explicitly not SSR certain pages?

Comment: Just a lot of reads being fetched from the DB that should be shown with a loading spinner rather than waiting for the server to fetch the data to display the entire page. Thanks for the info. I'll give it a shot :D

Comment: You can server-side render everything except the data, which you can keep client-side only. Setting up data fetching to work on the back-end is something that requires extra work and will not happen unless if you set it up: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props

Comment: One option is to still use SSR but then have client side fetches while showing the loading spinner. SSR doesn't stop you from doing any requests on the client :)

Comment: Nextjs, among other similar frameworks render their content initially as SSR, but also send over the blueprint for typical SPA's. When you first visit a site, it sends over the HTML, but also sends you the JS to render the rest yourself. Navigation inside the website is all client side after the initial page load. However, in Nextjs I believe you can make it hybrid as well to have some static pages not be needed to be re rendered on the server every time saving resources when pages never change.

Comment: @Issayah do you have a reference for Nextjs sending "over the blueprint for typical SPA's"? I haven't heard that before

Comment: @AndrewHulterstrom I primarily work with Nuxt, not Next, but you can view the behavior of how SSR apps built with these two frameworks work. When viewing one of their example sites -- https://demo.vercel.store/ as one of them, when viewing the network log, you can see that only one *document* is fetched. Navigating between routes never fetches new document pages. I'm not sure how Next prefers to work, but in Nuxt, all routes can have the added "prefetch" tag to auto import the route chunks. However, you can view the same behaviorin the Next demo app that it imports route chunks like normal SPA

Answer (score 4):

It is generally ***not recommended* to use a router other than `Next`'s** own router  with Nextjs. You can read about the process of migrating from React Router [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/migrating/from-react-router), but some of the reasons `Nextjs` has it's own router are:

> - It uses a file-system based router which reduces configuration
> - It supports shallow routing which allows you to change the URL without running data fetching methods
> - Routes are always lazy-loadable

Nextjs can work extremely well to meet **a mix of SSG/SSR/CSR** needs when it is used correctly.

I would highly recommend checking out the `Nextjs` documentation on Next's [approach to rendering](https://nextjs.org/learn/foundations/how-nextjs-works/rendering):

> The beauty of Next.js is that you can choose the most appropriate rendering method for your use case on a page-by-page basis, whether that's Static Site Generation, Server-side Rendering, or Client-Side Rendering.

Also, [this page](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/overview) from the docs can direct you to more specific information about the **types of rendering available** in `Nextjs` including a good overview of some implementation details.